# How can I apply an SVG to an MTL file?

Tags: 3d, three.js

I have a few SVGs that I would like applied to a materials file (MTL) of a 3D model (OBJ). I've seen that you can include .jpg and .png files in the materials file but have not seen how to include svgs.

```
...
newmtl just_tx:Cloth_ShapeSG:_designer
illum 4
Kd 0.00 0.00 0.00
Ka 0.10 0.10 0.10
Tf 1.00 1.00 1.00
bump TShirt.jpg -bm 0.15
Ni 1.00
Ks 0.21 0.21 0.21
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a bitmap in order to apply it to a material as a texture. Sfg is not a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a tool like [this one](http://www.svgtopng.com) to convert your SVG to a raster image. Afterward, you can edit the MTL with a text file editor and change the material's texture filename to the just created PNG file.